# dependency in pom.xml is not working in flink kafka connector example

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka, apache-flink

src code:

```
/*
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */


import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.MapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.utils.ParameterTool;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer082;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.SimpleStringSchema;

/**
 * Simple example on how to read with a Kafka consumer
 *
 * Note that the Kafka source is expecting the following parameters to be set
 *  - "bootstrap.servers" (comma separated list of kafka brokers)
 *  - "zookeeper.connect" (comma separated list of zookeeper servers)
 *  - "group.id" the id of the consumer group
 *  - "topic" the name of the topic to read data from.
 *
 * You can pass these required parameters using "--bootstrap.servers host:port,host1:port1 --zookeeper.connect host:port --topic testTopic"
 *
 * This is a valid input example:
 *      --topic test --bootstrap.servers localhost:9092 --zookeeper.connect localhost:2181 --group.id myGroup
 *
 *
 */
public class ReadFromKafka {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // create execution environment
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        // parse user parameters
        ParameterTool parameterTool = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);

        DataStream<String> messageStream = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer082<>(parameterTool.getRequired("topic"), new SimpleStringSchema(), parameterTool.getProperties()));

        // print() will write the contents of the stream to the TaskManager's standard out stream
        // the rebelance call is causing a repartitioning of the data so that all machines
        // see the messages (for example in cases when "num kafka partitions" < "num flink operators"
        messageStream.rebalance().map(new MapFunction<String, String>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -6867736771747690202L;

            @Override
            public String map(String value) throws Exception {
                return "Kafka and Flink says: " + value;
            }
        }).print();

        env.execute();
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.dataartisans</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka-example</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>kafkaex</name>
  <description>this is flink kafka example</description>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-clients_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-0.9_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>  
</dependencies>
</project>
```

versions :

```
kafka : kafka_2.12-2.4.0
flink : Apache Flink 1.9.1 for Scala 2.12
OpenJDK version: 1.8
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `flink-connector-kafka-0.9_2.12`, which is intended to be used with Kafka 0.9. You should be using

```
flink-connector-kafka_2.12
```

instead. This is the universal connector, which works with all recent versions of Kafka.

You will also want to change

```
DataStream<String> messageStream = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer082<>(parameterTool.getRequired("topic"), new SimpleStringSchema(), parameterTool.getProperties()));
```

so that you are using `FlinkKafkaConsumer` instead of `FlinkKafkaConsumer082`.

See [the documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/kafka.html#kafka-100-connector) for more details.